# Usign functions from __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my quest to become a better python programmer, I decided to organize my code better. One of the ways was to use config files instead of variables and proper logging things instead of just print out errors. After making it work, I learned that most people don't put that in their project files, but in `__init__.py`.

I tried to put both logging configuration, and the config filehandle inside the `__init__.py` and import the root directory, but it did not work.

I have the following tree:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── config.ini
│   ├── database.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

This is my `__init__.py` with basic stuff that I use in all my files:

```
"""Funções basicas usadas pelo progama"""

import os
import logging
import pathlib
import datetime
import configparser

#   Arquivo de configuração
CONFIG_FILE = 'config.ini'
CONFIG_PATH = ''.join([str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent), '/', CONFIG_FILE])

if os.path.exists(CONFIG_PATH):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(CONFIG_PATH)
else:
    logging.error(f'Conf file not found: {CONFIG_FILE}')


#   Create directories if not exist
try:
    if not os.path.exists(config['DEFAULT']['TempDir']):
        #   Temp dir
        os.makedirs(config['DEFAULT']['TempDir'])

    if not os.path.exists(config['DEFAULT']['Log']):
        #   Check log exists, if not create it.
        log_file = open(config['DEFAULT']['Log'])
        log_file.write(f"Created at {str(datetime.datetime.today())}")
        log_file.close()
    elif not os.access(config['DEFAULT']['Log'], os.W_OK):
        #   Check if you have permision to write
        logging.error(f"No permision to write: {config['DEFAULT']['Log']}")

except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f'Fail during creation: {e}')


#   Log
log_format = '%(asctime)s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(filename=config['DEFAULT']['Log'],
                    format=log_format, level=logging.DEBUG)


def get_conf(param):
    """Return a desired config file"""
    return config['CONF'][param]
```

And this is my database.py (just an example of the stuff I try to implement):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Database access.
"""

import pymysql
import logging
from app import get_conf
from pymysql import Error


def connect():
    """Abre coneção"""
    try:
        connection = pymysql.connect(host=get_conf('Address'),
                                     user=get_conf('DatabaseUser'),
                                     password=get_conf('DatabasePassword'),
                                     db=get_conf('Database'),
                                     charset='utf8mb4')
    except Error as e:
        logging.error(e)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    return connection, cursor


def close(connection):
    """Commita e fecha coneção"""
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()


def lookup(option, tell):
    """ Recebe uma opção e o telefone.
    Retorna ou a senha, ou a contrasenha baseado na opção.
    """
    try:
        connection, cursor = connect()
        if option == 'pass':
            col = 'password_col_name'
        else:
            col = 'counter_password_col_name'
        cursor.execute(f"""
            SELECT {col} FROM table_name WHERE col_phone_number = {tell};
        """)
        return cursor.fetchone()
    except Error as e:
        logging.error(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """Caso seja executado sozinho"""
    print(f"""
    Database: \t\t{get_conf('Database')}
    Address: \t\t{get_conf('Address')}
    Database User: \t{get_conf('DatabaseUser')}
    Database Password: \t{get_conf('DatabasePassword')}
    """)
```

When I try to execute database.py (it should just show me the variables, nothing more), I get an `ImportError` saying that is "most likely due to a circular import".

What is wrong? I am looking at some examples, and it seems right...

So, help me to write better code! :)

**UPDATE**
As some people suggest, I did try to use `from . import get_conf`, but I only got another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/richter/Documents/Projects/App/src/app/database.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import get_conf
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: try `from . import get_conf`. Importing app may import everything, including the file thats doing the importing

Comment: @9Guy, I first tried it, but got a error.

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import from `__init__.py` file using `.` since `__init__.py` is the initial of your application and its directory: `from . import your_imports`

And I guess, in your code it raises circular import error because you're importing logging both in your modules and then you are importing all of your module in another.

Comment: With a dot, I get another error.
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/richter/Documents/Projects/App/src/app/database.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import get_conf
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```